# CollectionView doesn't update unless I logout user

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, data-binding, uicollectionview

Hi I am Building a Xamarin App using a firebase realtime db that looks like this:

I have managed to make a collection view showing all the pets of the user by using the useremail as a key. However I am having a problem. If I add a new pet in the database on the addPetPage and come back to the page with the collectionView it doesn't update the collection view unless I logout the user then Log back in. Why would that be?

here is my code for the the ViewModel

```
class MyIDPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();

    public IList<PetProfile> source;
    public ObservableCollection<PetProfile> PetInfo { get; private set; }
    public IList<PetProfile> EmptyPetInfo
    {
        get => source;
        private set
        {
            if (value != source)
            {
                source = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EmptyPetInfo));
            }
        }
    }

    public MyIDPageViewModel()
    {
        source = new List<PetProfile>();
        CreatePetProfileCollection();
    }
   
    private async void CreatePetProfileCollection()
    {
        var petProfiles = await firebaseHelper.GetAllUserPetInfos();
        if (petProfiles != null)
        {
            EmptyPetInfo = new ObservableCollection<PetProfile>();
            foreach (var groupitems in petProfiles)
            {
                EmptyPetInfo.Add(new PetProfile() { PetName = groupitems.PetName, UserEmail = groupitems.UserEmail, Breed = groupitems.Breed, DOB = groupitems.DOB, Gender = groupitems.Gender, Weight = groupitems.Weight, CareInformation = groupitems.CareInformation });
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

ID xamlPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MyIDPageViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label 
               Text="My Id"
               VerticalOptions="Start" 
               HorizontalOptions="Start" 
               Padding="15"
               FontSize="Title"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="Name:" FontSize="Subtitle" Margin="15,0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label x:Name="UserName" FontSize="Medium" Margin="15,0"/>
        <Label Text="Email Address:" FontSize="Subtitle" Margin="15,0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label x:Name="UserEmail" FontSize="Medium" Margin="15,0"/>
        <Label Text="Phone Number:" FontSize="Subtitle" Margin="15,0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label x:Name="UserPhoneNumber" FontSize="Medium" Margin="15,0"/>
        <Label Text="Address:" FontSize="Subtitle" Margin="15,0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label x:Name="UserAddress" FontSize="Medium" Margin="15,0"/>

        <Label Text="My Pets:" FontSize="Large" Margin="15,0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding EmptyPetInfo}" >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                   Text="{Binding PetName}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Text="View Profile"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   VerticalOptions="End" />
                        
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                   Text="{Binding PetName}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Text="View Profile"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   VerticalOptions="End" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <Label Text="+ Add pet" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="AddaPet_Tapped"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
        <Button Text="Edit" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="15" Clicked="Edit_Clicked"/>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

FirebaseHelper:

```
public async Task<List<PetProfile>> GetAllUserPetInfos()
    {
        var useremail = Preferences.Get("UserSignInEmail", "");

        var PetProfiles = await GetAllPetInfos();
        await firebase
          .Child("PetProfiles")
          .OnceAsync<PetProfile>();
        return PetProfiles.Where(a => a.UserEmail == useremail).ToList();
       
    }
```

adding a pet to database code

```
 public async Task AddPetInfo(string petname, string breed, string dob, string weight, string gender, string careinformation)
    {
        var useremail = Preferences.Get("UserSignInEmail", "");                   
            
        await firebase        
          .Child("petProfiles")
          .PostAsync(new PetProfile() { UserEmail = useremail, PetName = petname, Breed = breed, DOB = dob, Weight = weight, Gender = gender, CareInformation = careinformation });              
    }
```

Comment: interesting.. how are you running this program? are you able to debug it?  are you able to determine if the constructor, `MyIDPageViewModel`, is called when you "come back to the page", can you clarify what you mean by coming back to the page?

Comment: What are you binding to? EmptyPetInfo? Then at the end of `CreatePetProfileCollection` you would need to raise the PropertyChanged event, since `EmptyPetInfo` is a List and does not notify anyone when items are added.

Comment: Running it on an android emulator on visual studio. Well on my idPage i can click on addPetPage. On this new page i can add details about a new pet that gets added to my  realtime db (I’ve checked they do appear on the db). However if I click back onto the idPage from addpetPage the pet doesn’t appear in the collectionview. I have also navigated to other pages then back to the idPage still no update. However if I stop debugging and run it again it will appear. 

How would I call the MyIDPageViewModel when I come back to the page?

Comment: well, as @Cheesebaron indicated, the Events of `ObservableCollection<PetProfile>` doesn't seem to actually be handled in this scope, and you aren't providing snippets indicating they are binded to controls.  However, I don't think there is anything to add to `CreatePetProfileCollection` here - I do think handling [CollectionChanged & PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) Events of your observable instance (or ensuring the type is binded in the control sense) is relevant.

Comment: I am personally more interested in how navigating away from this page and back again doesn't seem to be invoking the constructor of this type.  Though, it is probably just that I am unfamiliar to how Xamarin page navigation and types work.  By your description of navigating pages, it would seem instances of viewmodels persist in a given session.  That's probably the crux of what is being observed on here.

Comment: It is unclear how they navigate to begin with. If they retain the instance of the page, and navigate to it again, then the ctor wouldn't be called. The code snippet in the question is not sufficient to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I've updated the xaml page it is bind to. What other snippets would you like?

Comment: @chesesebaron I have tried what you asked still doesn't work

Comment: okay, so putting aside the constructor and navigation consideration: it's really just a matter of implementation here.  `await firebaseHelper.GetAllUserPetInfos()` seems to be used as a fetch here and iterated on once to construct a new instance of an observable (that new observable isn't actually observing on/over anything).. what type is `GetAllUserPetInfos` returning? (is it observable?)

Comment: @Caswell it is not observable. I've edited my question above so you can see it

Comment: where is the code for adding a new pet?

Comment: @jason i've edited the question to show the code for adding a new pet

Comment: you are just adding it to Firebase, there is no mechanism that will also update your CollectionView.  You can make your CollectionView listen for FB updates, or you can share a VM between the two pages, or pass a message to the CollectionView telling it to update.  But you have to DO something, the CollectionView will not magically update on its own.

Comment: @Jason I think you are right. But im clueless how could I get collectionview listen for FB updates? I have tried adding a command to the addPet button getting it to run CreatePetProfileCollection again. However that doesn’t work. Is there onappratt try ing I could call?

Comment: 1) Use FB to listen for updates, 2) use a common VM between both pages, 3) use MessagingCenter to pass a message when the data is added, 4) use an event or completion handler

Answer (score 0):

I would change the ViewModel code to something like this:

```
class MyIDPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();

    public ObservableCollection<PetProfile> EmptyPetInfo { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<PetProfile>();

    public MyIDPageViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(CreatePetProfileCollection);
    }
   
    private async Task CreatePetProfileCollection()
    {
        var petProfiles = await firebaseHelper.GetAllUserPetInfos();
        if (petProfiles == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        foreach (var groupitems in petProfiles)
        {
            EmptyPetInfo.Add(
                new PetProfile() 
                { 
                    PetName = groupitems.PetName,
                    UserEmail = groupitems.UserEmail,
                    Breed = groupitems.Breed,
                    DOB = groupitems.DOB,
                    Gender = groupitems.Gender,
                    Weight = groupitems.Weight,
                    CareInformation = groupitems.CareInformation
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

1. If you are using a ObservableCollection it makes no sense to use RaisePropertyChanged on the property, just instantiate and reuse the instance
2. You should avoid using `async void` unless you are using it for events. Even my modified code here, I would consider changing it to a pattern where you get the items in a lifecycle method instead of the constructor, as you are just firing and forgetting the `Task`.

If items still don't appear until you scroll the list or touch the CollectionView, you will need to wrap the code that adds items to the `ObservableCollection` in a piece of code that marshals back to the UI thread. Since you are using Xamarin.Forms, this can be done with `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`. In such cases I would extract a method from the foreach:

```
private void AddPetInfos(IEnumerable<PetProfile> petInfos)
{
    foreach (var groupitems in petProfiles)
    {
        EmptyPetInfo.Add(
            new PetProfile() 
            { 
                PetName = groupitems.PetName,
                UserEmail = groupitems.UserEmail,
                Breed = groupitems.Breed,
                DOB = groupitems.DOB,
                Gender = groupitems.Gender,
                Weight = groupitems.Weight,
                CareInformation = groupitems.CareInformation
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then wrap this method:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(AddPetInfos(petProfiles));
```

This would ensure you are adding items on the correct thread for the `ObservableCollection` to notify the View on the correct thread.